# View show/hide not working

Tags: iphone, xcode

In my HomeViewController there are homeView and loginView.when i cilck on logout button in homeview i hide the homeview and show loginView.So user get in the homeView.Again i click on logout button homeView not hiding

Appdelegte.m

```
HomeViewController *home =[[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:home];
    [viewsArray addObject:navigationController];
 [self.tabbarController setViewControllers:viewsArray];

homeViewController.m:

-(IBAction)logout:(id)sender
{
   homeView.hidden=YES;
   loginView.hidden=NO;

}
```

Comment: where you are creating homeView and loginView ??? post some more code....

Comment: Try to log something in logout Method. Is it working ?

Comment: i am not creating homeview and loginView programatically.I added those two views in HomeViewController.xib

Comment: it prints log.but not working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Things i can suggest looking at your code:

1- Make sure homeView and loginView are properly connected in IB and not nil.

2- Make sure that logout method is hooked with logout button and actually getting called.

hope that helps!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Make IBoutlet of homeView & loginView like this.

```
@property( nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIView *homeView;
@property( nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIView *loginView;
```

now connect your storyboard Views to coded IBOutlet views